# $router.push is only working the first time I call it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using VUE 2 - I have routes like this (debugging code is commented out):

```
{
    path: "/model-year/:model/:year",
    name: "ModelYear",
    component: TODO,
    // beforeEnter: (a,b,next) => {
    //   console.log("MY")
    //   next()
    // }
  },
  {
    path: "/model/:model",
    name: "Model",
    component: Model,
    // beforeEnter: (a,b,next) => {
    //   console.log("M")
    //   next()
    // }
  },
```

When I call `$router.push('/model/x')` it works

When I call `$router.push('/model-year/x/2020')` the URL in the browser changes, the current rendered component goes away but the new route is not rendered.

If I refresh the browser while the URL is on `/model-year/x/2020` the component displays properly.

On the first click, the route.name below is correct. On the second click (`/model-year/x/2020`) it is null. If I refresh on `/model-year/x/2020` it shows the correct name.

```
{{$route.name + ($route.params.id || '')}}
<b-container class="ml-3 mr-3" fluid>
  <router-view :key="$route.name + ($route.params.id || '')" />
</b-container>
```

So, it appears that $router.push only works the first time, and the second time it does not render the route, though it does change the URL and un-render the previous route.

I have also tried it without the `:key` on the router view.

Any ideas?

EDIT - Also, if I use the back button to go back to `/model/x` then forward to the `/model-year/x/2020` it renders properly there, too.

Here's the first page:

[image]

Here's the page on `/model/x`:

[image]

Here's the page on `/model-year/x/2020` after clicking:

[image]

Then, here is that exact same page after refreshing the browser:

[image]

Comment: You defined a route for `/model-year/:model/:year` but are pushing `$router.push('/model/x/2020')` -- if you change that `model-year` to `model` do you get the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: See my edit, it was originally /model for both routes but I changed it to be unique to troubleshoot - still same issue - I verify the path is right by refreshing the browser on the one that didn't render correctly and it works

Comment: well, now you've edited the question to make it so _none_ of the routes you defined match with what you're `push`ing; which certainly won't work. Can you confirm that what you're showing us is what you're actually doing?

Comment: OK, check now - added screen shots - the code is correct and you can see what's happening

Comment: Looking at your 'ModelYear' route at the top, the component is TODO. Is that an actual component or a note to yourself to implement it later?  Also, I think that a browser refresh reinitializes the Vue application.  If your project is in Github, can you import it into CodeSandbox?

Comment: TODO is a component, see the screenshot after reloading, it's just a red box with the route params printed in it. I use it in lots of places and it works OK as long as it's the first route.

Comment: Check your router hooks. This looks exactly like a mistake when transitioning from one path to another. Missing next() and similar mistakes..

Comment: I have 0 router hooks - this is a fairly new project and there are 3 routes (home, about, model) that are not the TODO component and the only hooks/guards are the commented out ones shown.